# Android: самый простой способ установки полупрозрачного цвета неактивным иконкам

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Рассматривается задача установки полупрозрачного цвета неактивным иконкам на табах (по [гайдлайнам](https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs) иконки должны быть прозрачными на 30%).

Первый вариант решения данной задачи - использование `<selector>` в отдельном xml-файле:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/testicon_select" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/testicon" />
```

Я так понял, что такой отдельный `xml`-файл должен быть для каждого таба, итого по 3 файла на таб:

1. основная иконка
2. полупрозрачная иконка
3. селектор

Не глупо ли? Я считаю, что такое решение неприемлемо в 21 веке.

Представленное ниже программное решение работает.

```
protected void initMainViewTabs(){

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabOne);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabTwo);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabThree);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabFour);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setAlpha(179);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setAlpha(179);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setAlpha(179);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setAlpha(179);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

Можно ли сделать его ещё лаконичнее? На данный момент, в нём много хардкода, но вероятно, на пока нет средств его сократить. Кроме того - как такое решение с точки зрения производительности?

Comment: Использование selector-а как раз таки и является более правильным решением, именно для этого они и были созданы. Вы можете отслежить огромное количествено состояний(state), что упростит сам код, так как некоторые действия програмно слишком сложно обрабатывать. В 21 веке, как и всегда, было такое понятие как clean code.

Comment: А можно тогда вместо ссылки на файл c иконкой напрямую добавить SVG-код в`<item android:drawable="">`?

Comment: скорей всего не получится, но все же вот тут посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742892/4829111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Множества промежуточных xml файлов можно избежать путем вложенностей:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/cerulean_pressed" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding android:right="16dp"
            android:left="16dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
...
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/cerulean" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding android:right="16dp"
            android:left="16dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Затем продумав дизайн можно описать стили и объединить их в темы. Если правильно подойти к этому этапу, то в следующий раз Вы просто скопируете шаблоны в папку `drawable` и в одном месте поменяете цвета (при условии, конечно, что в обеих случаях нет серьёзных кастомизаций и отклонений от рекомендованого варианта от Google). Скорость работы с таким подходом точно выше сравнительно с `Java`-методами.

Так как основная часть `UI` является статической (фон, шрифты, текстовые атрибуты, иконки и т.д.), а все варианты динамики должны быть предусмотрены, они все описываются в `xml` и такие файлы используются как ресурсы, которые нигде не пересекаются с логикой.

Использовать в этих целях `Java`, скорее всего, правильно когда пользователь очень сильно углубляется в изменения дизайна приложения и может все тонко настраивать, но даже в таком случае такие настройки придется хранить (и как вариант в том же самом `xml`).

Comment: Благдарю Вас за ответ. К сожалению, не получилось заменить `<shape>` на `<vector>` - пишет что `not allowed here`. Можно что-нибудь сделать?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu если Вы хотите изменять цвет иконки в зависимости от состояния, то самый правильный способ это добавить аттрибут `android:tint="@color/states', где `states(`/res/color/`) описывающий цвета разных состояний. `tint` в `ImageView`, в версиях ниже 21 будет вылетать `InflaterException`

Сделать селектор из векторов в одном `xml`-файле не получится. Не вдаваясь в подробности можно сказать, что каждая иконка это независимый компонент, который может переиспользоваться в многих местах, поэтому группирование ограничило бы доступ.